# minúscula a Mayúscula

Tags: c

Les quería preguntar por favor cómo funciona este código que hize con un libro de programación. Entiendo que pasa una letra minúscula a mayúscula, pero no entiendo porque "suma y resta caracteres". Me gustaría comprender como funciona esa parte. Muchas gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char minuscula_a_mayuscula(char minusc);

main(){

    char minusc, Mayusc ;

    printf("\nPor favor, introduce una letra minúscula: ");

    scanf("%c",&minusc);

    Mayusc = minuscula_a_mayuscula(minusc) ;

    printf("\nLa letra mayúscula equivalente es: %c", Mayusc);

}

char minuscula_a_mayuscula(char minusc){

    if (minusc >= 'a'  && minusc <='z'){
        return 'A' + minusc -'a';
    } else{
        return minusc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es porque se hace en base a un cálculo con los valores decimales que le corresponden a cada caracter. Si checas una tabla ascii te darás cuenta porque lo hacen. 
Básicamente lo que hace es calcular la "distancia" de la letra que se quiere convertir con la primera letra del abecedario, es decir, "a". Y ya que tiene esa distancia, calcula que caracter está a esa misma distancia de la 'A'. 
Podrías calcularlo matemáticamente si tomas la parte del return como fórmula. 
Por ejemplo: 
Si quisiéras convertir 'c' en 'C': 
Valores en decimal: 
'a': 97 
'A': 65 
'c': 99 
'C': 67

```
return 'A' + minusc -'a';
return 65 + 99 - 97;
return 67;
```

Que justamente es el valor decimal de 'C'.

Al asignar este entero a un `char`, automáticamente lo convierte en su valor ascii, es decir, a un caracter.

Otra cosa:
La función debería tener una condición de error, porque no cualquier valor que ingresen va a caer en el rango del abecedario.
Deberías poner un:

```
else if(minusc >= 'A' && minusc <= 'Z')
{
    return minusc;
}
else
{
    return '0';
}
```

Y si detectas un '0', mandar un error o algo así.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Tambien se puede usar `toupper` ;)